# Will Windows 10 allow my PC to see internal hard drive greater than 2TB?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-detection

Gigabyte motherboard EX-UD-3R.

It does not see more than 2TB of any internal hard drive.

My CPU is a first gen Intel core i7 and therefore it can run Windows 10 64bit. If I go ahead and buy Windows 10 64bit will this allow my PC to see >2TB?

Comment: No; It won't, you are limited by your hardware.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT

Comment: Based on a wee bit of research, it appears that there might be a solution, though you'll probably need to look into the details a bit.  Gigabyte has an unlock utility available for specific combinations of motherboards and processors.  See http://www.gigabyte.us/microsite/276/3tb.html to see if your system is eligible.  You may also want to see if you have the latest BIOS/firmware updates.

Comment: Some people are not shouting, they are near blind and have to use caps to see what they are typing.

Comment: @Moab: Capital letters are not necessary nor all that helpful. First, zooming in on the page is incredibly simple (CTRL+PLUS) or (CTRL+ScrollWheel). Second, research has shown that capital letters are harder to distinguish apart than lowercase letters (as capitals all have the same general profile). Reading comprehension is faster for properly capitalized sentences.

Comment: That is not what has been told to me by blind friends, I suppose it depends on what kind and severity of blindness, monitor etc.

Answer (score 4):

both yes and no

YES:
You can use 2.2TB or bigger drives under windows 7/8/10, they just have to be in GPT-mode

NO: 
You cannot boot to a 2.2TB drive under windows, unless your using UEFI/GPT

like this

You have 128GB SSD (windows) + 4TB harddrive
this will work, because you boot form the SSD

sources: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581408

Answer (score 1):

The 2TB limit (2.2TB actually) is not due to the OS but due to the way that most BIOS's use MBR to define the disks.

If your motherboard supports either UEFI, then you can use disks large than 2TB otherwise you cannot.

I think your motherboard is from 2010 or maybe a bit earlier? So it will not support UEFI.

Comment: 64 Bit MBR does not exist